# How to add base localization file in Localizable.strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, localization

I have and existing project which is using Base localisation.which have the file Localizable.strings(Base)

Like below screenshot

[image]

**I need to give support of Base localisation for my another existing project**

for that i have checked the project setting for "Use base internationalisation" but base is not in the list
And it should be create Base.lproj folder in my project but it is also not there.

[image]

[image]

So for the solution I have created Base.lproj folder manually  and add a string file with Localizable.strings(Base) name but not getting in list.

**----UPDATED------**

For the solution i got that i need choose(select) Localizable.strings and  check Base there like:

[image]

But i am not getting the base option in the list:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative way.

[image]

When you add the localization file you can set path where the file is created.
Change the path to Base.lproj then it would be localization file for `Base`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check the Base localization in for the viewcontroller. You can do this by tapping:

- Click on the viewcontroller

[image]

- Click on the File Inspector

[image]

- Check Base Localization

[image]

Also make sure this is checked. (I guess you have)
[image]

Comment: Also make sure this is checked. (I guess you have)?
I have check "Use base internationalisation"
But Base is not there.

Comment: @guru So you did my first steps aswell? And still not there?

Comment: I can not see the options i have xCode 10

Comment: I can see option only in storyboard

Comment: @guru please check you selected project instead of Target

Comment: Yes i am setting inside project setting only.

Comment: @guru Alright. I checked my app and I don't have the "base" localization either.

Comment: @guru So after I created my localizable.strings I didn't got any options of adding the base. (It's not there, even if I checked it in the "Localizations") hmmm